# Add conditions on Tychonoff space $X$ that guarantee that $X$ is perfectly normal.

Tags: general-topology

There exist Tychonoff spaces $X$ that are not perfectly normal. For example Uncountable Fort Space is a Tychonoff normal space which is not perfectly normal. Can we add conditions (maybe in cardinal invariants) on a Tychonoff space $X$ such that $X$ is perfectly normal?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, cardinal invariants are used already in the definition of a perfectly normal space, that is a space which is perfect and normal. A space $X$ is perfect if  $\psi(F,X)\le\omega$ for each closed subset $F$ of $X$.

Each regular semistratifiable space is perfect (in particular, each regular $\sigma$-space, each regular stratifiable space, each regular $\aleph$-space, each regular $M_1$-space, each regular Lasnev space) (see the Chapter “Generalized metric spaces” in “[Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology](http://webfile.ru/6475714)” for the definitions of these spaces).

The class of perfectly normal spaces contains: all discrete spaces ($\chi(X)=1$); all countable normal spaces ($|X|\le\omega$); all metrizable spaces (here you can use one of many metrization criteria, for instance, Bing-Nagata-Smirnov Theorem: a regular space $X$ is metrizable iff $X$ has a $\sigma$-locally finite (Bing, $\sigma$-discrete) base).

Also you can look at pages indexed with “perfectly normal space” in Engelking’s “General topology” for more complex conditions for the perfect normality of the space.

Answer (score 0):

The following well-known examples which are perfectly normal may be helpful for the question:

> 1 Metric space.
>
> 2 Topologist’s Sine Curve
>
> 3 Right Half-Open Interval Topology
>
> 4 Discrete space